# understanding kernel core pattern

Tags: kernel, coredump

I've install `systemd-coredump` service on my linux machine.
When I'm printing `kernel.core_pattern` I see the following output:

```
root@RMD0020A346FC81:/etc/systemd# sysctl -n kernel.core_pattern 
|/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t 9223372036854775808 %h %e
```

Which indicates that `systemd-coredump` is using this pattern to name and place the generated core dumps.

My question is what does this number in the middle of the core_pattern (9223372036854775808) means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `systemd-coredump` specific parameter. Judging from the [source](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/978642b633dc449bb7ab9494e09aec565d409d1d/src/coredump/coredump.c), it stands in for `RLIMIT`, the maximum soft core file size.